# Function call return value returned as aliased column not referenceable

Tags: postgresql

Can someone help me understand what's going on, here?

```
SELECT
    jsonb_array_length(to_jsonb("gi"."colors_distilled")) "gi_colors_distilled_jsonb_len"

FROM
    "general_inventories" "gi"

WHERE
    "gi_colors_distilled_jsonb_len" > 1;
```

Fails with:

```
-- ERROR:  column "gi_colors_distilled_jsonb_len" does not exist
-- LINE 6:     "gi_colors_distilled_jsonb_len" > 1;
```

This works (implementing the expression directly within the condition), however:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_array_length(to_jsonb("gi"."colors_distilled")) "gi_colors_distilled_jsonb_len"

FROM
    "general_inventories" "gi"

WHERE
    jsonb_array_length(to_jsonb("gi"."colors_distilled")) > 1;
```

It feels like I must be missing something obvious, but there's so little there that I must be botching an assumption about how/when aliases are evaluated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Not relevant to the question, but don't need to quote your identifiers (table, column, alias names) in PostgreSQL - using unquoted camel_case is far more legible anyway! Why have you tagged the question with both SQL Server **and** PostgreSQL? Please delete the inapplicable one - looks like PostgreSQL syntax to me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the `TRUE` order of operations in an SQL statement. It's a bit counter-intuitive, but once you grok the whole *Zeitgeist*, it'll fall into place and you'll understand why certain constucts won't work even though a novice may think they **should**!

### Order of operations:

From [here](https://builtin.com/data-science/sql-order-of-execution) (good explanation), it's:

- 1. `FROM/JOIN`
- 2. `WHERE`
- 3. `GROUP BY`
- 4. `HAVING`
- 5. `SELECT`
- 6. `ORDER BY`
- 7. `LIMIT/OFFSET`

So, we see that the `WHERE` comes **before** the `SELECT`, but it is in the `SELECT` where the aliases are defined, but the `WHERE` clause can't "see" the aliases because it's already been evaluated.

The `ORDER BY` clause on the other hand comes **after** the `SELECT` and therefore you **can** use aliases in that clause!

Your own question is answered within the link.

> For example, a common mistake in SQL is incorrectly referencing column aliases.

Take a look [here](https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/) for another take - explains how MySQL sometimes ignores these and the problems it can lead to (`STRICT_MODE` being OFF - never run MySQL this way). The author (Lukas Eder) is always worth looking out for (YouTube for example).